# How to do this in gulp browserify?

Tags: gulp, browserify

how to transform this in gulp ?
since i couldn't get the same result when i do this in gulp.

Here is the grunt file :

Thanks.

```js
    browserify: {
      debug: {
        options: {
          browserifyOptions: {
            standalone: 'Mosaico'
          },
          watch: true,
        },
        files: {
          'build/mosaico.js': ['./src/js/app.js', './build/templates.js']
        }
      },
      main: {
        options: {
          browserifyOptions: {
            debug: true,
            fullPaths: false,
            standalone: 'Mosaico'
          },
          // transform: ['uglifyify'],
          watch: true,
        },
        files: {
          'build/mosaico.debug.js': ['./src/js/app.js', './build/templates.js']
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Why can't you make the same in gulp? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I want to use mosaico in my app, but the demo is using grunt. My current app is using gulp, so it should be converted to gulp. could you help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how grunt works and why you use standalone and watch:true, but this is how I usually manage to build with browserify:

```
var opts = {
  entries: ['build/mosaico.js': ['./src/js/app.js','./build/templates.js'],
  debug: true,
  //watch: true,
  //browserifyOptions: {
  // standalone: 'Mosaico'
  //},
};

var options = assign({}, watchify.args, opts);

gulp.task('debug', function() {
 return browserify(options)
 //If you need to use transform 
 .transform('plugin-to-use')
 .bundle()
 //Create custom name for destination
 .pipe(source('file-name-for-destination'))
 //Destination folder
 .pipe(gulp.dest('destination'));
});
```

If you want also watchify, try this:

```
var watchfiles = watchify(browserify(options));
  watchfiles.on('update', function(){
  //Start normal task - debug
    gulp.start('debug');
  });
```

I didn't test that setup, maybe there are some issues as I tried to customize it for you but feel free to ask.

Comment: wow thanks, apparently i just need to add the source('blah').